# KML and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-3

This is an example for OpenLayers 3: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/kml-earthquakes.html

I copy the code and paste in my project of Visual Studio 2012, but it doesn't work.
After I download the examples directly from this page: http://openlayers.org/download/

I open any of the HTML examples but it doesn't work. Why would it work online and not locally from my PC. Do I need to import any additional library?

Comment: Only appears the basemap... but the kml not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had opened your browser's JS console you'd see something like this:

> ol.js:278 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/(...snip...)/v3.15.1/examples/data/kml/2012_Earthquakes_Mag5.kml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

The explanation can be [easily found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local), the simplest solution would be to run a local web server that would expose your local the examples folder over HTTP. Arguably the easiest solution is to use python's in-built HTTP server. From inside of your `OpenLayers/v3.15.1/` folder execute:

> python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000

or, if you're using Python 3:

> python -m http.server 8000

Then, once you navigate to http://localhost:8000/examples/kml-earthquakes.html you'll see the example correctly loading exactly like the version deployed on openlayers.org.

Comment: Hi, thanks for u answer... I can´t. in the folder examples i found file "simple_http_server.py" need i run this file?... i paste the folder examples in local web server but i can´t see correctly the example..  I don´t speak english and is difficult understeand, sorry. and thanks

Comment: The commands only need Python installed, you don't need to add any new files. Can't comment on the *"can't see"* - this sounds less and less related to OpenLayers. Also, you may try to use Google Translate if in doubt.

Comment: The problem was relationed about my IIS... I configured & worked... Really thanks...